# How do I extract an entire table that contain scroll down in page

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Why when I'm extracting the table using the method .getElementsByTagName it doesn't extract all data contained in table? Note that is a scroll down in page https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MGLU3.SA/history?p=MGLU3.SA.

```
Public Sub getHistoricCotation()

    Dim mainURL As String
    Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object
    Dim S, R, C
    Dim initial_date As String, final_date As String
    Dim stock As String

    initial_date = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970 00:00:00", ufHistorico.txtDtInicial) + 86400
    final_date = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970 00:00:00", ufHistorico.txtDtFinal) + 86400
    stock = ufHistorico.cbAcoes.Text

    mainURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & stock & "/history?period1=" & initial_date & "&period2=" & final_date & "&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d"

    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", mainURL, False

        strCookie = .getAllResponseHeaders
        strCookie = Split(Split(strCookie, "Cookie:")(1), ";")(0)

        .Open "GET", mainURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Cookie", strCookie
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
        .send

        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = S
        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each tRow In elem.Cells
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = tRow.innerText
            Next tRow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portion your script could parse are the static ones but the portion it was unable to parse generates dynamically. However, the good news is all the content of that table are available in page source  within some script tag. I've created a script to scoop out the desired portion from there. All you wanna do now is process the content using any json converter or regex.

This is how it scrapes all the relevant data from there:

```
Sub FetchHistoricalPrice()
    Const mainUrl$ = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MGLU3.SA/history?p=MGLU3.SA"
    Dim S$, Elem As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", mainUrl, False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True

        .Pattern = "HistoricalPriceStore[\s\S]+prices[^[]+(.*?]),"
        Set Elem = .Execute(S)
        If Elem.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Elem(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```